# ALE project root for Python

Tags: vimscript, plugin-ale, python

I use ALE to run linters while editing Python code in vim. When working on code in a package, I can't get ALE to respect the pylint configuration in the project root. I've had it in `.pylintrc` as well as in `pyproject.toml`, both in the root directory of the project. Digging in a bit more, I find this is because ALE isn't correctly identifying the root directory of the project. I think this is because ALE [uses vim's alternate file](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/autoload/ale/python.vim#L21) rather than the current file in finding the project root. (i.e., `#` rather than `%`.)

**Actual behavior**: In terms of the package structure described below, I use vim to open `config.py`, which contains this line: `from . import error as err`. ALE's pylint flags it as a "relative-beyond-top-level", which it's not - the package works fine with the Python interpreter. Using `:ALEInfo` shows me that pylint was run from `top/src/package/` rather than `top/`. No custom `~/.vimrc` is installed.

**Expected behavior**: ALE runs pylint from the correct directory and this line is not flagged as an error.

**My question**: Is this an ALE bug or am I using it wrong? I don't understand why you would use the alternate file rather than the current file in finding the project root.

Here's the project structure:

```
top/
    [config files including setup.py, setup.cfg, pyproject.toml]
    [other directories]
    src/
        __init__.py
        package/
            __init__.py
            config.py
            error.py
            [other files]
```

Complete `:ALEInfo` output:

```
 Current Filetype: python                                                                                                                                    
Available Linters: ['flake8', 'mypy', 'prospector', 'pycodestyle', 'pyflakes', 'pylint', 'pyls', 'pyre', 'vulture']
  Enabled Linters: ['flake8', 'mypy', 'pylint']
 Suggested Fixers:
  'add_blank_lines_for_python_control_statements' - Add blank lines before control statements.
  'autopep8' - Fix PEP8 issues with autopep8.
  'black' - Fix PEP8 issues with black.
  'isort' - Sort Python imports with isort.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'yapf' - Fix Python files with yapf.
 Linter Variables:
let g:ale_python_flake8_change_directory = 1
let g:ale_python_flake8_executable = 'flake8'
let g:ale_python_flake8_options = ''
let g:ale_python_flake8_use_global = 0
let g:ale_python_mypy_executable = 'mypy'
let g:ale_python_mypy_ignore_invalid_syntax = 0
let g:ale_python_mypy_options = ''
let g:ale_python_mypy_use_global = 0
let g:ale_python_pylint_change_directory = 1
let g:ale_python_pylint_executable = 'pylint'
let g:ale_python_pylint_options = ''
let g:ale_python_pylint_use_global = 0
 Global Variables:
let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'always'
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 0
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:
(executable check - failure) flake8
(executable check - failure) mypy
(executable check - success) /Users/will/github/top/env/bin/pylint
(finished - exit code 2) ['/opt/homebrew/bin/bash', '-c', 'cd ''/Users/will/github/top/src/package'' && ''/Users/will/github/top/env/bin/pylint''  --output-format text --msg-
template="{path}:{line}:{column}: {msg_id} ({symbol}) {msg}" --reports n ''/Users/will/github/top/src/package/config.py''']
<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
[various style complaints omitted]
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just a quick note that that line of code is not really looking for an alternate file, it's using `#` together with `a:buffer` which is a buffer number passed as an argument, so you can see that `:echo expand('#1:p:h')` will show the directory of file opened as buffer 1. You can see buffer numbers from output of `:ls` or `:buffers` commands... (Sorry, haven't had the time yet to think of why you might be having trouble with your issue specifically.)

Comment: You can also use something like `:echo ale#python#FindProjectRootIni(bufnr())` and/or `:echo ale#python#FindProjectRoot(bufnr())`, etc. to see what ALE thinks is the Python project root is, maybe that would help you troubleshoot the issue a little further?